# Escape bug from special formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper, code-formatting

In Visual Studio 2012 using ReSharper, how can I prevent the word `bug` in a comment from being formatted differently than the rest of the comment?

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: That's not a native VS feature. Are you using Resharper?

Comment: I admit, I just tried it -- and sighed in disappointment when nothing changed.

Comment: You can use "BG" in comments, but it seems odd to put the word bug in a summary tag.

Comment: @pcm2 Yes I am. I didn't realize it was specific to ReSharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of R#, not Visual Studio.

Go into the R# options, and at the bottom under the Tools heading, there's a section for "To-do items" - that will include "Bug" which defines the regular expression used to find the word "bug" in your comment. You could delete that To-do item or just change where R# looks for it.